# AspectJ passing in main args

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, aspectj

I am trying to figure out how to pass in arguments using the ajc command for AspectJ. My command is the following:

```
ajc -classpath ./build/:./build/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar -argfile $ASPECTJARGS
```

Basically the same command used to work in java but instead we had (where `arg1` and `arg2` are stared in the `$ASPECTJARGS` now):

```
java -classpath ./build/:./build/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar arg1 arg2
```

Then the main function would take `arg1` and `arg2` directly. Now I get an

```
unrecognized single argument: arg1
```

error when I run the ajc command and am wondering if there is another way to pass in the arguments to the main function through compilation of ajc.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure I get the question but this works for passing in the args to ajc:

```
export ASPECTJARGS="Foo.java -1.8 -showWeaveInfo -verbose"

ajc -classpath ./build/:./build/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar $ASPECTJARGS
```

Just like it would for invoking java. If you want to use argfile then you create a file (e.g. named `thefile`) with these contents:

```
-1.8
-showWeaveInfo
Foo.java
```

Then run ajc:

```
ajc -classpath .build/:./build/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar -argfile thefile
```

Or via a shorthand:

```
ajc -classpath .build/:./build/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar @thefile
```

Comment: This is not what I meant. I would like to pass in arguments to ajc as I would in java. In other words, pass arguments to the main function through the String args[ ] array.

Comment: As I said, not entirely sure I understood the question.  What do you want to pass that isn't an option that will change the behaviour? A concrete example would be great. You can bypass the launch script if you need to - open ajc or ajc.sh and look at how it invokes java to launch the main entry point in the compiler.

Comment: I have experienced this error message on Windows when e.g. the path to the AspectJ runtime contained spaces as in "C:\Program Files\Java\AspectJ\lib\aspectj.jar" and I used this directly or indirectly (via ASPECTJ_HOME) in my ajc classpath without quoting the classpath. Try to enclose your classpath in double-quotes and see what happens. I have not tried on Linux lately, so I do not know if it helps.

Comment: Update: I tried on Linux and if I have something like `export ASPECTJ_HOME="/opt/aspectj 1.8.9"` (note the space!), `export PATH="$PATH:$ASPECTJ_HOME/bin"`, `ajc -cp $ASPECTJ_HOME/lib/aspectjrt.jar:mylib/my.jar -sourceroots myproject/src -d myproject/bin ...` (note the missing quotes around the cIasspath!), I get the error you mentioned. The problem could also be in one of the unquoted source or detaination paths, I have not tried that variant.